# OSD Notify problem with VMware workstation full screen

Tags: notification, notify-osd, vmware-workstation

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with two monitors. 
The primary monitor is my laptop monitor (HP EliteBook 8570p) and the second one is 24' LG, which i use for my VMware Workstation 10 guest os.
I noticed then i put VMware guest mashine in full screen OSD notify doesn’t work. When Vmware Workstation is in console view OSD is working ok.

Has anybody experienced the same behaviour?

Tnx,
Ivan